# How to add repeated values array with adding both values

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array like this. it contain three array list and two are same product id here what i want to do , add both price and quantity values in the list and make that to a sing array

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 882
            [order_id] => 814
            [product_id] => 192
            [quantity] => 40
            [price] => 410.0000
            [total] => 16400.0000
            [product_value] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 881
            [order_id] => 815
            [product_id] => 200
            [quantity] => 20
            [price] => 1049.0000
            [total] => 20980
            [product_value] => 60
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 882
            [order_id] => 815
            [product_id] => 192
            [quantity] => 10
            [price] => 410.0000
            [total] => 4100.0000
            [product_value] => 25
        )

)
```

So here, I want an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 882
            [order_id] => 814
            [product_id] => 192
            [quantity] => 60
            [price] => 410.0000
            [total] => 24600.0000
            [product_value] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 881
            [order_id] => 815
            [product_id] => 200
            [quantity] => 20
            [price] => 1049.0000
            [total] => 20980
            [product_value] => 60
        )   
)
```

I tried condition code like this but didn't work it properly

```
    foreach ($product as $key => $products) 
            {

                foreach ($product as $keys => $row) 
                {

                    if ($products['product_id']==$row['product_id']) 
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
           }
```

so somebody please help me to figure it out please

Comment: i'm assuming in the "what i want array" you want 882 price to be 820 not 410

Comment: beside the fact the alex answer is correct, i think a proper solution would be a modified `query` from your db, show your db `query`.

Comment: dude went awol.

Answer (score 3):

This should work nicely. Essentially we are giving each array a key based on the id in a new array and over each iteration we check if we've already done the previous and if so we add the price and quantity:

```
$array = array(

    0 => array(
        'order_product_id' => 882,
        'quantity' => 40,
        'price' => 410
    ),
    1 => array(
        'order_product_id' => 881,
        'quantity' => 20,
        'price' => 1049
    ),
    2 => array(
        'order_product_id' => 882,
        'quantity' => 10,
        'price' => 410
    )

);


$mod_arr = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $id = $item['order_product_id'];
    // we've already created this item? yes: add together current item price and quantity with previous
    if (isset($mod_arr[$id])) {
        $mod_arr[$id]['quantity'] = $mod_arr[$id]['quantity'] + $item['quantity'];
        $mod_arr[$id]['price'] = $mod_arr[$id]['price'] + $item['price'];
        continue;
    }
    $mod_arr[$id] = $item;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($mod_arr);
```

Generates:

```
Array
(
    [882] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 882
            [quantity] => 50
            [price] => 820
        )

    [881] => Array
        (
            [order_product_id] => 881
            [quantity] => 20
            [price] => 1049
        )

)
```